# Complete Cryptocurrencies Data

Tags: data-science, blockchain, data-analysis, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I am working on cryptocurrencies blockchain data and I want data from the beginning of the time of that particular cryptocurrency. Is there any way to download complete block data in the Postgresql file?

https://blockchair.com/dumps is although offering this but they limit the download speed and number of downloading files. Moreover, I am also waiting for their reply. Meanwhile, I am finding some other ways or websites to download complete data of multiple cryptocurrencies in SQL format. I cannot download the .csv or .tsv file because it takes a lot of space on my laptop. Therefore, I want to use any other format (preferably .sql format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is depends on cryptocurrency, you have. I can suggest you, how to fetch data from Bitcoin-compatible crypto, i.e. [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.org/en/), [Emercoin](https://emercoin.com/en), etc.
The cryptocurrency node (wallet) has [JSON RPC API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)) interface.Usinf this API, you retrieve all your data with following commands from this [command list](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list):

- Get total block counter with command `getblockcount`.
- Iterate block number from 0 to result of `getblockcount`. For each number, call `getblockhash`.
- For result of `getblockhash` call `getblock`. This function provide transactions list, enclosed in this block.
- For ech transaction (nested loop), call `getrawtransaction`. Hint: if you call `getrawtransaction` with 3rd argument "1", node automatically decodes transaction, and return you decoded transaction in JSON.

You can extract from a transaction vectors `vin` and `vout`, and upload all data into your SQL database.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot, @olegarch. That was useful for now. But would definitely ask more in the same perspective in case I don't get the data that I want.

Comment: You can contact me in telegram with same username "@olegarch"

Answer (score 0):

You can find the data for about 40 chains here at https://explorer.bitquery.io/ and download it in JSON or CSV format.

Any questions you have ask them in the community: https://community.bitquery.io/